# How to customize Shorewall firewall logs

Tags: fedora, iptables, firewall, rsyslog, logger

I am using Fedora 13 machine with shorewall installed.
shorewall 4.6.6-RC1
iptables v1.4.7

Below is log format by shorewall:

```
Oct 23 05:28:17 localhost kernel: shorewall:LAN-LAN:ACCEPT:IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=224 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=47578 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=45747 DPT=5000 LEN=204
```

My question is that is there any way/method to make shorewall/iptables to dump logs in a custom format as i want 
for example like

```
Oct 23 05:28:17 localhost kernel:
shorewall:LAN-LAN:ACCEPT:IN_INTERFACE= OUT_INTERFACE=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=224 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=47578 DF PROTO=UDP SOURCE_PORT=45747 DESTINATION_PORT=5000 LEN=204 SENT_BYTES=0 RECIEVED_BYTES=something
```

Comment: Please please please please upgrade your Fedora version if you are using it for anything security-sensitive (or, really, on the network at all).

Comment: Yeah ,I am going to move to CentOS 7

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. Shorewall uses the [standard netfilter log format](http://logi.cc/en/2010/07/netfilter-log-format/). While you can customize some aspects of Shorewall's logging behavior (mostly to do with [log tags](http://shorewall.net/shorewall_logging.html#idp43077360)) the basic format is fixed.